# How to add new custom elements to a list via gitOps

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart where I have defined some default environment variables. If I try to add new env's to the values.yaml file in gitOps my default values get overridden. I assume this is because of the fact that lists are treated in helm as immutable values. Is there a way to add new custom elements to the list without overwriting the default values?

Helm template .yaml file:

```
container:
  extraEnv:
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.container.extraEnv }}
    - name: {{ $key }}
      {{- $value | toYaml | nindent 12 }}
    {{- end }}
```

Helm values.yaml file:

```
container:
  extraEnv:
    - name: SECRET_1
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: tls-secret-1
          key: ca.crt
    - name: SECRET_2
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: tls-secret-2
          key: ca.crt
```

Comment: I'd be a little surprised to see raw Kubernetes YAML in externally-visible configuration like that.  Can you move the "standard" environment variables into the template file, or into a helper template?  You also might consider having two separate lists of "standard" and "extra" environment variables, so that you can emit both.  I'm guessing from the description that your build system is committing an extra values file that sets its own `container: { extraEnv: }`, and yes, this overrides the chart's defaults rather than extends it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can confirm that I have to separate lists of "standard" and "extra" environment variables. I have just pasted the extraEnv part here. So how would the implementation look like if I would choose to go with a helper template further?